# stack variables from netCDF file

Tags: stack, raster, netcdf

I'm working with several netCDF files. Each nc file has 33 variables. I need to create a stack for each nc file with these 33 variables to do some calculations, but the only way I know is to convert each variable in a rater and stack them, one by one... Like this:

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
library(rgdal)

nc_data <- nc_open('./data/GCAM/RAW/93d4aa096b15491b1ba136b46d8063cdca59d253c75d59791b4d4cb6f8a1ae91/Project ID 68344/GCAM-Demeter/GCAM-Harmonized/Mean_Std/GCAM_Demeter_LU_H_ssp1_rcp26_modelmean_2030.nc')

PTF0 <- nc_data$var[[1]]
data1 <- ncvar_get( nc_data, PTF0 ) 

data1 <- raster(data1)

plot(data1)
```

Can anyone help to automatize this?? I'm thankful in advance

[This is a structure of the NetCDF file, I highlight the files that I need to stack, actually, I need stack just PT1 to PTF8](https://github.com/Tai-Rocha/Forest_Scenarios/blob/main/doc/images/stackoverflow.png)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing now could be done like tis

```
f <- 'GCAM_Demeter_LU_H_ssp1_rcp26_modelmean_2030.nc'

library(raster)
r <- raster(f, "PTF0")
```

(assuming that "PTF0" is a variable name)

But if you want to create a single object for multiple variables in one step, use `terra` instead

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(f)
```

You can specify the variables you want

```
 rr <- rast(f, c("PFT1", "PTF2"))
```

You can also create a SpatRasterDataSet and then extract the variables you want like this

```
s <-sds(f)
x <- rast(s[2:8])
```

Comment: Actually, this was my first attempt. But I receive error:

`Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘raster’ for signature ‘"ncdf4"’` 

I also tried the second way with terra package. But I receive the same error

Comment: Then you are doing something else. You need to use a filename, `f` in my example. You cannot use a `ncdf4` object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mr Robert! With these few lines, I solve the issue and I can do all I need.

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
library(rgdal)
library(terra)

f <- nc_open('./data/GCAM/RAW/93d4aa096b15491b1ba136b46d8063cdca59d253c75d59791b4d4cb6f8a1ae91/Project ID 68344/GCAM-Demeter/GCAM-Harmonized/Mean_Std/GCAM_Demeter_LU_H_ssp1_rcp26_modelmean_2030.nc')

rr <- rast(f$filename)

rrr <- rr[[2:8]]

plot(rrr)

soma <- sum(rrr)

plot(soma)
```

Now I'll spend more time thinking about how to automate this... because I need to do this operation for each one of  NetCDF files...